# Spring-Boot adding basic http security to REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I am tasked with building a REST service which requires authentication on a couple of actions, while permitting anonymous users on others.

For example:

```
| Path         | Requires authentication |
| /add         | YES                     |
| /{name}      | NO                      |
| /report/{id} | YES                     |
```

However I'm having issues with setting up spring-security to work this way.

If I override `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` `configure` function like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()                
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()                
            //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/{name}").permitAll() // I can't really specify a dynamic url here, can i?
            .anyRequest().authenticated();                
}
```

With this configuration, any action I invoke will first display the standard browser basic authentication pop-up form. That is what I want, except I don't want this on the dynamic url `/{name}` action.

So instead I tried removing `.anyRequest().authenticated()` and activating `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations with 
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass = true, prePostEnabled = true)`
and add annotations to controller actions as following:

```
| Path         | Annotation                         |
| /add         | @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") |
| /{name}      | @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")       |
| /report/{id} | @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") |
```

With this the `/{name}` action allows anonymous users as expected, however `/add` and `/report/{id}` actions now just return "Access is denied" with status 500, instead of forcing basic auth.

How can I force basic authentication on select controller methods while allowing anonymous access on others?

Comment: Please post full stack trace. Are you using jersey framework?

Comment: @IssamELATIF There is no stack trace since no exception gets propagated to stdout/stderr. Spring security probably handles access denied exception by itself in one of it's filters. No I'm not using jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the configuration for every urls should do the trick :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       .csrf().disable()                
       .and()
       .httpBasic()
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests()                
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/add").authenticated()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/report/*").authenticated()
       .anyRequest().authenticated();                
}
```

Comment: This works. I should've thought of explicitly setting urls to authenticated. I presume the order is mandatory due to rule propagation (if `permitAll` for `/*` was at the bottom then it would override `/add`)? Also what is the difference between `antMatchers(*).authenticated/permitAll()` confguration and method level annotations such as `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize`? I believed they are equivalent.

Comment: The order is not important, Spring is configuring the most specific URL first and then overwrite it with the less specific configuration and so on. I'm not sure but I think that by using the Secured and PreAUthorize annotations, Spring created a second WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter for the annotations which is not configure to use basic auth and then overwrite the first WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter.  This remains a supposition.

Comment: Spring-Boot ver 1.5.4.RELEASE yields compile error "The method and() is undefined for the type HttpSecurity" (?)